# how to show predictions on test data from multiple models in time series forecasting

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I split AirPassenger data into train and test, fit three different exponential smoothing models on train, and then made prediction on test. What I need is to plot predicted results from all models on test data, along with the original data. Could anyone help with plotting all of them together on one plot? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
train <- window(AirPassengers, end=1957)
test <- window(AirPassengers, start=1958)
fc1 <- ses(train, h=5)
fc2 <- holt(train, h=5)
fc3 <- hw(train, seasonal='additive')

autoplot(AirPassengers)+??????
```

Comment: See this example: https://otexts.org/fpp2/accuracy.html#examples-1

Comment: @Rob Hyndman  Thank yo very much, professor.  This is what I need. But if I need to predictions on test data, how can I get the predicted value on test data? Is there anything like `predict(fc, testdata)`?

Comment: Set h=length(testdata)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
AP <- cbind(AirPassengers, train, test, 
        as.ts(fc1)[, 1], as.ts(fc2)[, 1], as.ts(fc3)[, 1])
autoplot(AP)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: does not seem like what I want.  How can I get the predicted value on test data from each model? @G. Grothendieck

Comment: It shows all 6 series.  I have added an image of the output so you can see that indeed it shows them all.  If you only want some of them remove those from the definition of AP.

Comment: Thank you ,  @G.Grothendieck     what I need is the plot multiple lines predicted based on test data.  the link from Professor Hyndman's comment has some nice examples

Comment: It does show this. fct1, fct2 and fct3 are three distinct lines showing the three forecasts.

Comment: I mean prediction on the whole test data.

Comment: Use `fitted(fct1)`, etc.